# How to combine 2 columns in a day-hour format and convert them into a year-month-day-hour format？

Tags: python

I have a excel(dataframe) like this:

```
Day Hour Value
1   0      0.13
1   1      0.15
1   23     0.14
……
365   0    0.17
365   1    0.15
365   23   0.11
```

I want to convert the first two columns to the date of this year or any year and then put the day in the position of the month and day, and then concatenate the hours, like this：

```
DateTime                 Value
2022-01-01 0:00:00       0.13
2022-01-01 1:00:00       0.15
2022-01-01 23:00:00      0.14
……
2022-12-31 0:00:00       0.17
2022-12-31 1:00:00       0.15
2022-12-31 23:00:00      0.11
```

How to use pandas or numpy to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue:

Code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from datetime import datetime

# Simulate the above dataframe
days = list(range(1,366))
hours = np.random.randint(0,24, 365) 
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": days, "hour": hours})
```

[image]

```
# Checkif the year is a leap year

def isLeap(y):
    return (y % 100 != 0 and y % 4 == 0 or y % 400 == 0)

# Get day and month given the integer of a day, i.e when (when 1-365 is given)

def getMonthDay(d, y):
     
    calendar = {
        12: 31,
        11: 30,
        10: 31,
        9: 30,
        8: 31,
        7: 31,
        6: 30,
        5: 31,
        4: 30,
        3: 31,
        2: 28,
        1: 31
    }
    
    if (isLeap(y)):
        calendar[1] +=1 
    
    m = 1
    days = d
    while days > 0:
        day = days
        days -= calendar[m]
        if days < 1:
            return m, day
        m += 1
    
    return None


    
# Function to apply on the Dataframe where you save as datetimeformat
def datetime_merge(day, hour, year=2022):
    e_month, e_day  = getMonthDay(day, year)
    e_datetime = datetime(year=year, day=e_day, month=e_month, hour=hour)
    
    return e_datetime

# Apply the Function
df["DateTime"] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime_merge(x.day, x.hour), axis=1)

# Result is
```

[image]

```
# You can then drop the unnecessary column 
df.drop(["day", "hour"], axis=1)

# FinalResult
```

[image]